# Is there a way to display a single calendar in multiple subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar

My organization's SharePoint is set up so that each department has it's own subsite.  I have a calendar on one subsite, that I would like to be able to display on the parent site and another subsite.  Is there a way to display the calendar so that an update to one is reflected in the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendar Overlay is a choice for you. You can add the view of calendars in other sites in your current calendar. You can refer to this article:[Overlay a SharePoint calendar with a calendar from Exchange or SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overlay-a-sharepoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-exchange-or-sharepoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a) for specific steps.

Also there are some other calendar options you can consider, just have a look at this [A review of all the calendar options in SharePoint and Office 365](https://sharepointmaven.com/a-review-of-all-the-calendar-options-in-sharepoint-and-office-365/)

Answer (score 0):

is this a Classic SharePoint Calendar?

if so, you can use the overlay option,

first you need to create a Normal Calendar on the site you want to display and then on than calendar use the Overlay option and display the calendar from a different site.

This way you can have calendar views from other calendars displayed across different calendar,

you can also display up to 8 different overlays into a single calendar